# Firefox 81 not working with Amazon Music

Tags: music, amazon

Amazon is asking to update my Firefox, which is not possible because it comes packaged with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Is there a timetable when Ubuntu is pushing Firefox to  82? Any hints how this problem goes away are most appreciated.

Comment: Think this is more Amazon being wonky than Firefox being out of date.  Would install a user agent switcher and use firefox on windows setting, bet it works.  Cannot see a three week old version as out of date.

Comment: Today I got an update to 81.02. Unfortunately Amazon is still not happy. User agent does not work. I can not load music.amazon.de
Google Chrome is working (86.0.4240.75). I don't like to use chrome, but I have no choice, I guess.

Comment: Unfortunately this is more of a problem between Firefox and Amazon which we( the users) can't fix.  Would let Firefox know so maybe later it will work again.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.1 updated firefox to 82. Amazon music is working again.